# How to change the background color of the micro editor in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, micro-editor

I am using micro editor.

How to change the background color and other settings of the micro editor?

Is there any config file for it, if there is then what is the location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Micro uses **COLORSCHEME**.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
  set colorscheme gotham (Enter)

If you (Tab) will see other themes.

Config files:

- `~/.config/micro/init.lua`
- `~/.config/micro/settings.json`